# Defining a room that is equally lit at every point

Tags: geometry, vectors

Imagine you were in a room designed such that no matter where in the room you stand, a sphere of volume 1 liter held at 2 meters above the ground would be exposed to the same amount of light. How would this room be designed, and lights placed?

Note that objects need not be equally lit from all sides, simply lit such that the total amount of light hitting the sphere is the same. Also note that illumination is inversely proportional to the square of distance between source and sphere. Finally, this condition need only be true at 2 meters above ground.

Comment: It doesn't matter, at all, how you design the room. As long as it's thermally completely isolated, it will automatically achieve that state. You wouldn't want to be in it, as it would be very hot in there, but that's the one and only solution that is possible. Every other solution will not be in thermal equilibrium, hence it will not be equally lit.

Comment: Are you suggesting allowing the interior of the room to auto ignite, satisfying the illumination requirement?

Comment: I am suggesting that the only solution is thermodynamic equilibrium, in which case the shape of the room doesn't matter. Indeed, you couldn't even tell that you are in a room. :-)

Comment: You're dodging the question. It's a question of geometry

Comment: If the question is what you said it is, then it's not about geometry, at all. That's the beautiful thing about thermodynamics, it's completely independent of it. The other possibility is that the person who asked the question didn't want to hear the correct physical solution, to begin with, in which case you asking the wrong people. I think you may get better answers in engineering or mathematics, but they will be incorrect, as far as physics is concerned.

Comment: The question was asked in mathematics, and then migrated here

Comment: If you or whoever asked it expects a different solution, then it should stay in mathematics, IMHO. Physics is about how nature behaves, not about how certain idealized models of nature behave. If the walls of your room would be lit in such a way that the energy flow would be independent of direction, then the walls would be invisible, i.e. their shape would not matter.